# How to prepare a random 1-qubit superposition for data encoding

Tags: quantum-gate, unitarity, state-preparation

Let's assume we have a normalized data vector $\vec{x}= [x_1,x_2]$. How can I prepare a state $$|\psi\rangle = x_1|0\rangle+x_2|1\rangle$$
for any $\vec{x}$. I know that this state is in general not reachable through a single rotation, but is there a systematic way of finding a sequence of unitaries (let's call it $U_s$ here), that performs a transformation, such that $U_s|0\rangle=|\psi\rangle$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** Suppose $U$ is a unitary operation on a single qubit. Then there exist real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ such that
$$ U = e^{i\alpha} R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma)R_z(\delta) $$

This is on [page 175 of this textbook.](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

Ignore the global phase, each of these gates can be [implement directly](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RYGate.html) on a quantum computer. So given a vector $\vec{x}$, you just work-out what $U$ needs to be, then find the appropriate angles  $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ . To find $U$ that takes $|0\rangle$ to $\vec{x}$, note that $U$ must take the form $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & u_{12} \\ x_2 & u_{22} \end{pmatrix}$. To get the second column, pick some arbitrary vector that is independent from $\vec{x}$, then perform the the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

---

If you use Qiskit, you can initialize your state directly. For example:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_state
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

num_qubits = 1
random_initial_state = random_state(2**num_qubits) #you can place specific vector here
circuits = []
circuit = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits,num_qubits)
circuit.initialize(random_initial_state, 0)
```

Comment: +1 Note that you can avoid Gram-Schmidt and just set $u_{12} = \overline{x_2}$ and $u_{22} = -\overline{x_1}$. Substitute into dot product to see how this works.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thanks for the comment. You made a good point. That will indeed create a unitary matrix. I was just trying to give a general procedure at how one can systematically do such thing.